# Programmatically quit "Captive Network Assistant" without disconnecting from network

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, captivenetwork

Is there a way to quit or kill Captive Network Assistant in (Mountain) Lion, without disconnecting from the network?

I have tried to do a simple `killall` command and also a `killall -9`, but it still disconnects from the network anyway.

Alternative is there a way of telling Captive Network Assistant, that I have logged in on the webpage and it should re-check it?